# flyout dropdown with delay on hover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for suggestions on a better way to do my multi dropdown on hover.  The current implementation doesn't stick and I've tried a couple jquery functions to alleviate the issue with a delay.  I would like to delay so that the parent dropdown menu doesn't disappear until you leave the entire hierarchy. I am currently using bootstrap 4.

```
<div class="dropdown-content" style="overflow: auto;
                                min-height: 425px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column nav
                    nav-tabs">
                <a data-toggle="tab" href="shopping.html">
                    <div class="fa fa-home"> </div>Home
                </a>
                <!--Shopping-->
                <ul class="mainDropDown">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu" role="menu">
                        <a tabindex="1" href="searchResults.html">
                            <div class="fa fa-tags">
                            </div>Shopping
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu" role="menu">
                                <a tabindex="1" href="searchResults.html" id="appleStoreMenuLabel">
                                    Apple Store</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">iPods
                                        </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">iPod
                                            Accessories
                                        </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Watches</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Mac
                                            Systems</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">iPads</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Shop
                                            All
                                            Apple
                                            Store</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu" role="menu">
                                <a tabindex="1" href="searchResults.html" id="babyMenuLabel">
                                    Baby</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Clothing</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Feeding</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Gear
                                        </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Maternity</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Nursery
                                        </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Care
                                            & Safety</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Shop
                                            All Baby</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu" role="menu">
                                <a tabindex="1" href="searchResults.html" id="booksMenuLabel">
                                    Books</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu
                                        dropup">
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Autobiography
                                            &
                                            Biography</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Cooking
                                        </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Health
                                            &
                                            Fitness</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">History</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Humor
                                        </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Juvenile
                                            NonFiction</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Juvenile
                                            Fiction</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Religion</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Social
                                            Science</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Sports
                                            &
                                            Recreation</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Shop
                                            All
                                            Books</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu" role="menu">
                                <a tabindex="1" href="searchResults.html" id="electronicsMenuLabel">
                                    Electronics</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            2 </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu" role="menu" id="fashionAccMenuLabel">
                                <a tabindex="1" href="searchResults.html">
                                    Fashion
                                    Accessories</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            2 </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu" role="menu" id="giftBasketsMenuLabel">
                                <a tabindex="1" href="searchResults.html">
                                    Gift Baskets</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            2 </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu" role="menu" id="homeGardenMenuLabel">
                                <a tabindex="1" href="searchResults.html">
                                    Home & Garden</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            2 </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu" role="menu" id="jewelryMenuLabel">
                                <a tabindex="1" href="searchResults.html">
                                    Jewelry</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            2 </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu" role="menu" id="moviesMenuLabel">
                                <a tabindex="1" href="searchResults.html">
                                    Movies</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            2 </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu" role="menu" id="musicMenuLabel">
                                <a tabindex="1" href="searchResults.html">
                                    Music</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            2 </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu" role="menu">
                                <a tabindex="1" href="searchResults.html" id="officeProductsMenuLabel">
                                    Office Products</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            2 </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu" role="menu" id="onSaleNowMenuLabel">
                                <a tabindex="1" href="searchResults.html">
                                    On Sale Now!</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            2 </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                            3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <!--Events-->
                <ul class="mainDropDown">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu" role="menu">
                        <a tabindex="1" href="searchResults.html">
                            <div class="fas
                                    fa-ticket-alt"
                                style="margin: 0 5px
                                    0 0;">
                            </div>Events
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                    1 </a></li>
                            <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                    2 </a></li>
                            <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                    3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!--Travel-->
                <ul class="mainDropDown">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu" role="menu">
                        <a tabindex="1" href="searchResults.html">
                            <div class="fa
                                    fa-plane">
                            </div>Travel
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                    1 </a></li>
                            <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                    2 </a></li>
                            <li><a href="searchResults.html">Link
                                    3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <hr class="w-100">
                <a data-toggle="tab" href="searchResults.html">
                    <div class="fa fa-certificate">
                    </div>On Sale!
                </a>
            </div>
            <!--End of DropDown Container Style-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 tab-content">
            <!--second level here-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 tab-content">
            <!--3rd level here-->
        </div>
        <!-- Image Mapping to Department/Shopping parent categories-->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-end
                    align-content-end">

                <div><img src="http://rewardtrax.com/isiprogram/images/Final_Apple_150.png"
                        class="img-fluid" id="appleStoreLogo" style="display: none"></div>
                <div><img src="http://rewardtrax.com/isiprogram/images/Final_Electronics_150.png"
                        class="img-fluid" id="electronicsLogo" style="display: none"></div>
                <div><img src="http://rewardtrax.com/isiprogram/images/Final_Jewelry_150.png"
                        class="img-fluid" id="jewelryLogo" style="display: none"></div>
                <div><img src="http://rewardtrax.com/isiprogram/images/HomeGarden_150.png"
                        class="img-fluid" id="homeGardenLogo" style="display: none"></div>
                <div><img src="http://rewardtrax.com/isiprogram/images/Final_Sale_150.png"
                        class="img-fluid" id="onSaleNowLogo" style="display: none"></div>
                <div><img src="http://rewardtrax.com/isiprogram/images/Final_Movies_150.png"
                        class="img-fluid" id="moviesLogo" style="display: none"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End Image Mapping-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is really hard to answer a question about a bug in code when the question includes a huge block of code. When this happens, it takes much longer and is much more difficult for other users to search through the code to find the pieces that are relevant to the problem. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/20800345)

Comment: ok.  I am a novice with opening up questions on stack overflow.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).